# Radio button with action not working on Ember.js

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, radio-button

I got a table with different radio buttons in each line, when I assign an action to the radio button and click it, the changed attribute is not set to true, and the radio button stays empty, even though the action was executed.

Example:

```
<input type="radio" name="x" value="value" {{action 'helloWorld'}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Radios aren't part of core Ember. Try using a library like [ember-radio-button](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-radio-button). It gives you a `changed` property which you can use to send out an action.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Instead of putting a direct action on the input, set it to the input's onchange like this.

```
<input type="radio" name="x" value="value"
       onchange={{action 'helloWorld' value="target.value"}}>
```